# What does » mean in code collab ?

Tags: perforce, code-collaborator

I'm using code collab and perforce for versioning. Sometimes I get a diff which says the only different is `»` between two lines. It's really annoying. What does this character mean ?

Comment: My guess is a TAB character. Have you got an ASCII editor, where you could inspect what your whitespaces really are? (Especially spaces vs. tabs.)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a whitespace change.